# Save a pointer to member function of derived class

Tags: c++, boost, delegates

I am looking for a way to save a pointer to a member function of a derived class.

For exemple:

```
class A
{
public:
    typedef void (A::*FunctionP) (int a);
};

class B : A 
{
public:
    void Test(int a)
    {
        //Do stuff
    }
    B()
    {
        FunctionP theFunc = &B::Test;
    }

};
```

The following code dose not compile..
Is there another way to do this? (Using template's maybe, or boost)

(Btw class A is an abstract class witch one of its implementations is invoking functions saved as FunctionP)

Thank you

Comment: You might want to read about [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) and [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind). Boost have equivalent functionality if your compiler isn't C++11.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a `static_cast`:

```
FunctionP theFunc = static_cast<FunctionP>(&B::Test);
```

Coliru: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2cfed4926aed43db

Still, it might be even better to use `std::function` and `std::bind`, depending on your needs.